# About $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\, d\lambda^n(x)=0$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$ be continuous and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\, d\lambda^n(x)=0$.

Show that $f\equiv 0$.

Give a counterexample when we drop the property that $f$ is continuous.

Giving a counterexample is easy. A staircase function not vanishing on a null set will do.

For example $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty), f(x)=\begin{cases}0,~~\text{if $x\neq 0$}\\ 1,~~\text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}$.

This function is not identically $0$, but has integral equal to zero.

Now to the other question.

The function $f$ is measuarable, as it is a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$.
Furthermore $f$ is integrable, since $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\, d\lambda^n(x)=0$.

Now by Fubini we have:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\, d\lambda^n(x)=0=\int_\mathbb{R}\dotso\int_\mathbb{R}f(x_1,\dotso, x_n)\,dx_1\,dx_2\dotso dx_n=0\Leftrightarrow \int_\mathbb{R} f(x_1\dotso, x_i,\dotso, x_n)\, dx_i=0$ for some $1\leq i\leq n$.

[This is because in the reals a product is zero iff one of the factors is $0$.]

So it suffices to prove the statement for $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx=0$.

Suppose $f$ is not identically $0$. Then there is some $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f(\xi)\neq 0$. Hence $f(\xi)>0$.

Now since $f$ is continuous it exists for $\varepsilon = 1$ a $\delta >0$ such that whenever $|x-\xi|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(\xi)|< 1$.

So $\int_{\xi-\delta}^{\xi+\delta} f(x)\, dx <\int_{\xi-\delta}^{\xi+\delta} f(\xi)+1\, dx=2\delta(f(\xi)+1)>0.$

As $f$ is non-negative, we have $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\, dx \geq\int_{\xi-\delta}^{\xi+\delta} f(\xi)\, dx>0$, which contradicts the hypothesis.

Is this correct?
Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: The conclusion that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x_1, \dots, x_i, \dots, x_n) dx_i = 0$$
for some $i$ is incorrect.  You can't just separate out the multi-dimensional integral into a product of one-dimensional integrals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Can you however give a hint towards a correct solution?

Comment: I'd recommend using induction on $n$.  Show that this holds true for $n = 1$, then convert $f : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$ into a continuous function $\hat f : \mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ by setting
$$\hat f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1, \dots, x_n; x) dx.$$

Comment: Ok, so my proof for the $n=1$ case wasnt for nothing. Is it correct however? :) Then the induction is immediate when we assume it is correct for $n$, after your "rewrite".